# Configuring routers in Packet Tracer - Simpler configuration

Tags: router, packet-tracer

I am fairly new to packet tracer and know what I need to move forward with trying to figure out how to make something work in packet tracer.

I have 2 PCs.  Each one is connected to a router on each side of the router

This is how I am displaying them in packet tracer in this way with the icons.

PC0        Router0        Router1        PC1

The 2 routers are connected to each other.

**PC 0** has IP: 172.19.100.50 with default gateway 172.19.1.1

**PC 1** has IP: 172.16.200.50 with default gateway 172.16.1.1

In order to get the other information I need to configure the router interface in CLI for the router I need an additional IP address for the shared network created between 2 routers.

This is what I came up with.

**PC 0**
IP: 172.19.100.50
Subnet mask 255.255.0.0
Default gateway 172.19.1.1
Network: 172.19.0.0

**PC 1**
IP: 172.16.200.50
Subnet mask 255.255.0.0
Default gateway 172.16.1.1
Network: 172.16.0.0

**Does the information I have here look accurate and do I have the correct network IP to configure the router interface?**

My entries would be as follows in the router configuration if correct.

**Router Interface 0 (First Router)**
•   IP address: 172.19.0.0 255.255.0.0

**Router Interface 1 (Second Router)**
•   IP address: 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0

I configured the PCs and I configured the first router partially in CLI when I realized I was missing the router interface IP for the second interface entry as well for this first router.

Your feedback is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just configure the router interfaces towards the PCs with the default gateway IPs: `172.16.1.1/16` and `172.19.1.1/16`. You can't use an IP address with all host-part bits zero like `172.16.0.0/16`.
- You haven't described how the routers are connected. In case it's via Ethernet, they'll require IP addresses on the interfaces between them, e.g. use `172.31.255.0/31` and `172.31.255.1/31`.
- Each router needs to have a route to the remote network it can't see directly, the one behind the other router. Either configure a routing protocol like OSPF between the routers, or manually configure static routes.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that is what I was looking for. The IP addresses on the interfaces. I got the wrong ones. Your examples are the correct ones then? 
Does the order in which I use them matter or can they be added to either ?  172.31.255.0/31 for first router interface and 172.31.255.1/31 for the second router interface.

And yes I will then continue with configuring the protocol between the routers.

Comment: There are no "correct" ones. You can use any address for the router interfaces within the select subnets as long as you also set them up as default gateway on the connected end nodes. Also, remember to vote for useful answers and eventually accept one of them that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and tip.  This answers what I need.